# AWK - how to add a full stop?

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a file:

```
fakdfal
14867
kgjafdfrf
8423685
```

I want to get the result:

```
fakd.fal
14.867
kgjafd.frf
8423.685
```

Comment: Try this:- $ awk '/[^.]$/{$(NF+1)="."}1' FS= OFS= file

Comment: Using `sed` is easier:  `sed 's/...$/.&/'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/...$/, ".&"); print}'
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/...$/.&/'
```

Comment: Make it even simpler: `awk '{sub(/...$/, ".&")} 1'`

Comment: @anubhava: yes, it is less code; no, it is not as clear. I'm not that frantic to save 3 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed it is simpler:

```
sed -i.bak 's/...$/.&/' file
```

OR awk solution:

```
awk 'length($0)> 3 {l=length($0); $0=substr($0, 1, l-3) "." substr($0, l-2)} 1' file
```

Comment: `s/...$/.&/` is simpler still, and doesn't need the non-portable `-r` option.  And I'm not convinced about the `-i.bak` (was the output meant to be on standard output, which is more generally useful, or back into the original file).  There's a reason Unix scripts write to standard output; it is more flexible than overwriting the input file (and works better when standard input comes from a pipe, and ...).

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, I edited along with longish awk also.